# feature extraction in python for nlp

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I am trying to extract features like "delhi police" , "newyork police" using python regular expression. in short city and police name separated by space. 
 so city name will be differed and "police" will be constant.

Can I do using named entity recognition for location + "police" as a constant.

if yes HOW.?  any sort of regular expression can you provide.

Comment: What about "the problem of corrupted police"? Should "corrupted police" be extracted? I'm not sure in which country "corrupted" is...

Comment: no actually for my project of finding crime location this feature like city +space+police will be useful. so I am looking for this feature from news article.

Comment: https://txt2re.com/index-python.php3?s=delhi%20police&3 <- automated service that generates regexes.

Comment: delhi is just an example.....there can be any city of world followed by space and than police......

Comment: it should be generalized such that any city + police ...so i am trying to implement with ner tag and police ..and looking for that knid or regex

Comment: ULTIMATELY LOOKING FOR REGEX WHICH SATISFY NEED OF             " ANY CITY NAME + POLICE" .

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
test_string = "The New York Police, New Delhi police and other police departments are fighting crime".lower()
cities = ['new delhi', 'new york']
regex = "(("+"|".join(cities)+") police)"
regex = regex.lower()
results = re.findall(regex, test_string)
print([res[0] for res in results])
#['new york police', 'new delhi police']
```

Comment: it is still redundant ....for your approach I need to mention all cities in "cities" variable .   Can we make it   more general like any city + "police" ..?

Comment: This would be the easiest way to do it - it's not that hard to compile a list of cities.An alternative could be to use an existing NER package such as the stanford NER to recognize just the city, and then check if the next token is 'police',  OR, to train your own NER to recognize the city + police combinations. But to do that, you'd need training data first, which you don't have.

Comment: if location tag is matched than how to get next token from set of tokens.?